# How to show the marker upfront in openlayers3 while drawing the polyline

Tags: openlayers-3, polyline, markers

I am drawing the polylines on the map and displaying few marker as well which is working fine but when the polyline is drawn marker is above the line

I wanted to know like can the shown the marker upfront when i draw the polyline

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">-->
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>

<script>
    var map;
    var vectorLayer;
    var extentToZoom;
    var geojsonObject;
    function drawPolyline(geoObject){
        var image = new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: null,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'red', width: 1})
        });
        var styles = {
            'greenRoute': new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'green',
                    width: 3
                })
            }),
            'redRoute': new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'red',
                    width: 3
                })
            })
        };
        var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution) {
            return styles[feature.get("fName")];
        };
        geojsonObject =geoObject;
        var routeGeom = new ol.format.Polyline(
                {
                    factor: 1e6
                }).readGeometry(geojsonObject.route_geometry, {
                    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
                });
        var colourRoute=["greenRoute","redRoute"]
        var routeFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry:routeGeom,
            fName: colourRoute[Math.floor(Math.random()*colourRoute.length)]
        })
        console.log("color route"+colourRoute[Math.floor(Math.random()*colourRoute.length)]);
        extentToZoom = routeGeom.getExtent();

        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [routeFeature]

        });

        //vectorSource.addFeature(new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Circle([5e6, 7e6], 1e6)));

        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: styleFunction
        });
        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    }
    function initMap(){
        map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                        urls : ["  http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/openriverboatmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png","  http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/openriverboatmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png","  http://a.tile.openstreetmap.fr/openriverboatmap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"]

                    })
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
                    collapsible: false
                })
            }),
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([103.986908, 1.353199]),
                rotation: 68*Math.PI/180,
                zoom: 18
            })
        });

    }
    function invokeAddMarker(){
        var markerData = [
            {
                "title": 'point1',
                "lat": 1.350664,
                "lng": 103.985190,
                "description": 'yyyy'
            }, {
                "title": 'point2',
                "lat":1.353604,
                "lng": 103.986395,
                "description": 'zzz'
            }, {
                "title": 'point3',
                "lat": 1.357227,
                "lng": 103.9879999,
                "description": 'uuu'
            }
        ];
        for(var i=0;i<markerData.length;i++){
            addmarker(markerData[i].lat,markerData[i].lng);
        }
    }
    function addmarker(lat,lng){
        console.log("*****lat******"+lat);
        console.log("*****lng******"+lng);
        var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lng,lat],'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
            name: 'camera'
        });
        var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 46],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                opacity: 0.75,
                src: 'camera.png'
            }))
        });
        iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);
        vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [iconFeature]
        });
        /*t clear the markers*/
        /*vectorSource.clear();*/
        vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource
        });
        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        map.on('click', function(evt) {
            var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
                    function(feature, layer) {
                        return feature;
                    });
            if (feature) {
                alert("video comes here");

            }

        });
    }
    initMap();
    invokeAddMarker();
    geojsonObject ={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["1DYUCf____89vE8AWwAAANkCAAAAAAAAcAAAAG_vKABaqAAATqcUAIO1MgYAAAEB","1DYUCf____89vE8AEAAAAHAAAADZAgAAAAAAAG_vKABaqAAAtZkUAPGvMgYBAAEB"],"checksum":4294707914},"route_name":["T3 Arrival Drive","T3 Arrival Drive"],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"{srqAewyieEzrExuAtDhA","via_indices":[0,2],"route_instructions":[["10","T3 Arrival Drive",418,0,2,"418m","S",202,1,"N",22],["15","",0,2,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.35355,103.986563],[1.350069,103.985137]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":418,"total_time":65,"end_point":"T3 Arrival Drive","start_point":"T3 Arrival Drive"}};
    drawPolyline(geojsonObject);
    var geoobject2={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["UiQkCf____-ljiMAEAAAABgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP____-jqAAAt5gUAG2wMgYAAAEB","c8gaCf____8AAAAAMgAAALAAAAAAAAAAHQEAAOviEAajqAAAdqQUABy3MgYAAAEB"],"checksum":4089551480},"route_name":["East Coast Parkway (ECP)",""],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"mjkqAyewieEsHuB_m@qWoYwJuDoDoAqBoFaJkCsD}H_Hai@{Pw`@iM","via_indices":[0,10],"route_instructions":[["10","East Coast Parkway (ECP)",18,0,2,"18m","N",21,1,"S",201],["1","",308,1,24,"307m","NE",28,1,"SW",208],["1","",65,9,5,"65m","NE",23,1,"SW",203],["15","",0,10,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.349815,103.985261],[1.352822,103.986972]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":391,"total_time":29,"end_point":"","start_point":"East Coast Parkway (ECP)"}};
    drawPolyline(geoobject2);
    var geoobject3={"status":200,"hint_data":{"locations":["NksUCf_____CwU8AzwAAABMBAAAAAAAAHQEAAG0BpwavqAAARaEUAOmxMgYAAAEB","R0sUCf_____CwU8AZgAAAPQAAADtAAAAKwIAAKQJ8QSvqAAAebIUAGy5MgYBAAEB"],"checksum":3361836982},"route_name":["T3 Departure Drive","T3 Departure Drive"],"status_message":"Found route between points","route_geometry":"isoqAq}wieEqUiHqpA__@cLkE}NgJyGaDiTmGemAk`@w`@kM","via_indices":[0,8],"route_instructions":[["10","T3 Departure Drive",535,0,81,"535m","N",22,1,"S",202],["15","",0,8,0,"0m","N",0,"N",0]],"via_points":[[1.352005,103.985641],[1.356409,103.987564]],"found_alternative":false,"route_summary":{"total_distance":535,"total_time":84,"end_point":"T3 Departure Drive","start_point":"T3 Departure Drive"}};
    drawPolyline(geoobject3);
    map.getView().fit(extentToZoom,map.getSize())
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here drawpoline() method will draw the lines using osrm service and invokeAddMarker() method has a array for which addmarker()[image] method is invoke

i wanted shown something like above

Comment: They are displayed in the order you add them to the map. Add markers after you draw lines.

Answer (score 0):

All `ol.style.Style` settings have a `zIndex` parameter.  You can use this to set the order of different styles.

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/apidoc/ol.style.Style.html